# How to pass params from a file in .bat execution

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a large param list in test.txt file and i want to pass them in the below java execution command. I am not sure whats the correct syntax if someone could help with the correct way / syntax ?

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties -Dother_prams=xxxxx -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -cp .;**>>test.txt**;resources\ABC_LIB%EMBEDDED_JBOSS_BOOTSTRAP_LOC% com.mypackage.myprogram %2 >> ..\Logs\MyProgram_Log_%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%.txt
```

Or is it possible to execute the Java command like below?

java < MY_TEXT_FILE_WITH_JAR_NAMES_IN_IT.txt %2 >> ..\Logs\MY_LOG_FILE_PATH.txt

Comment: Do you want a batch file? And what is the structure of test.txt?

Comment: How does the program expect these parameters? Do you just want to pass the filename?

Comment: Its a flat text file which contains the additional comma separted values which i want to pass to this program.